# transfer queue-instance between already running processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Simple example to explain my question:
I have three processes
parent process P
two child processes A and B

P starts A and B
with the start there are two queues implemented: Queue between P and A (PA) and Queue between P and B (PB)

Now process A initiates another Queue and wants to share this with B. Is there any way to do this or have all queues to be implemented by starting of the processes?

Comment: It depends upon the type of queue instance you create. If you create a normal `queue.Queue` instance it cannot be shared as it lives in the process memory and can be shared only between threads. Whereas, if you create an instance `multiprocessing.Queue` it can be shared, as it lives in the shared memory and can be shared between processes.

Comment: that's clear. but i want to know if it is possible to share a multiprocessing.Queue that is instantiated after all processes have been started. If the queue is instantiated from process A how can it be shared to process B? I cannot put it in another queue because a queue-instance is not pickable.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. The correct way is to create a queue instance before creating the processes and passing the queue instance as a parameter to the processes so that they can communicate between them using the queue.